# Factorial contract errors in version 0.5.1

Tags: solidity

This factorial contract is worked in 0.4.24 version, there were warnings, but it is raising errors in version 0.5.1. How to solve the problem?

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract factorial{

    uint number;
    uint fac=1;
    uint i;

    function fact(uint x) public view returns(uint) {
        number=x;
        for(i=1;i<=x;i++){
            fac= fac*(i);
        }
        return fac;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: i changed the code now if u try this in 0.5.1 you'll get this error 'TypeError: Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable.
number=x;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error tells you you are modifying the state and that is not allowed in `view` functions.

Your function modifies the contract-level variables. Such variables are stored in the state and are therefore stored in the blockchain. `view` functions can't make actual modifications to the state and to the blockchain as they are executed only locally on your own node - unless you call them from another non-view function.

Simply move your variables inside the function and it's a working `view` function - if that's what you want.